# Retrieve full path of FTP file on drag & drop?

Tags: vb.net, ftp

I can read the filename using next code when dragging a file from an Ftp folder browsed on Windows explorer.
But is there a way to retrieve the full Ftp path?

```
    Private Sub DataGridView1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.DragDrop
    Dim filename As String = ""
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent("UniformResourceLocator") Then
        Dim ioStream As System.IO.Stream = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData("FileGroupDescriptor"), System.IO.Stream)
        Dim contents As Byte() = New [Byte](511) {}
        ioStream.Read(contents, 0, 512)
        ioStream.Close()
        Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim i As Integer = 76
        While contents(i) <> 0
            sb.Append(CChar(ChrW(contents(i))))
            i += 1
        End While

        filename = sb.ToString()
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data dropped contains a UniformResourceLocator format, you can get the entire URL from that, for example:

```
   Private Sub Form1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragDrop

      If e.Data.GetDataPresent("UniformResourceLocator") Then
         Dim URL As String = New IO.StreamReader(CType(e.Data.GetData("UniformResourceLocator"), IO.MemoryStream)).ReadToEnd
      End If

   End Sub
```

It first checks to see if a UniformResourceLocator format exists, and if so, gets the data from e (the drag/drop argument), converts it to a MemoryStream, and passes that to a new StreamReader (for easy reading), then does a .ReadToEnd() to get the entire string.